# Como fazer um pedido GET a cada linha com jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Olá,

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$('#checar').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'checar.php',
        data: { lista: $('#lista').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#sucesso').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Página HTML que o código acima está em execução:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Checar Usuário</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sucesso"></div><br><br>
    <textarea id="lista"></textarea>
    <button id="checar">Checar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

checar.php:

```
<?php
$usuario = $_GET['lista'];
$usuarios = 'usuario2|usuario4|usuario6|usuario8';
if(stristr($usuarios, $usuario) !== false) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Na textarea, o usuário vai informar a lista de pessoas que ele quer verificar se existem no `$usuarios`, então vai conter mais de 1 linha.

Gostaria que quando o usuário clicasse em `Checar`, o jQuery enviasse um pedido GET à cada linha, por exemplo, tem 5 linhas, cada linha contendo `usuario1|usuario2|usuario3|usuario4`, o jQuery enviasse um pedido GET nessas 5 linhas, e agrupasse todas linhas inteiras que o PHP retornou como false, e todas as linhas que o PHP retornou como true.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acho que esse trabalho, tendo em conta que é para dividir os encontrados dos não encontrados e enviar como resposta, devia ficar para o lado servidor:

checar.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['nomes'])) {
    $arrNomes = explode("\n", $_GET['nomes']);
    $usuarios = 'usuario2|usuario4|usuario6|usuario8';
    $nomesValidos = explode('|', $usuarios);
    $found = array();
    $notFound = array();
    foreach($arrNomes as $nome) {
        if(in_array($nome, $nomesValidos)) { // existe
            $found[] = $nome;
        }
        else {
            $notFound[] = $nome;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode(array('found' => $found, 'not_found' => $notFound));
    die();
}
```

Ajax/HTML:

```
<textarea id="lista"></textarea>
<button id="checar">Checar</button>
<div id="sucesso"></div>
<div id="errors"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#checar').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'checar.php?nomes=' +encodeURIComponent($('#lista').val()), // manter os espaços
      success: function(data) {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          $('#sucesso').html('<b>Encontrados: </b>' +data['found'].join(', '));
          $('#errors').html('<b>Não encontrados: </b>' +data['not_found'].join(', '));
      }
  });
});
</script>
```